# Improving answer visibility by listing top answers on top

Tags: feature-request, questions, design

I am working on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365746/whats-the-fastest-way-to-convert-hex-to-integer-in-c/34366370#34366370) Q&A, and I was wondering if it is actually possible to improve the visibility of the answers.

Actually the accepted answer spans 4+ screens tall , mainly because of pasting the graphs and figures. I doubt that users can actually see even the second or third answers.

Would it be possible to have a division above all answers where top 3-4 answers are horizontally listed along with their respective score. The user could click there to see each of them.

Comment: That would be cool. Maybe one day when we don't have a fixed-width design...

Comment: If we had VR headsets we could have virtually unlimited width screens. We'd just have whiplash and neck RSI problems.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it is a great idea, especially when viewing posts like that.

If you're not interested in waiting, here is an extremely minimal approach using a userscript that won't take [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/307724) to implement :)

It grabs the top 4 posts (*skipping the first one*) based on the selected sort method (*active, votes, oldest*).

It provides a link to the post, shows the vote count and adjusts the vote icon based on the score.

To [install](https://github.com/enki-code/UserScripts/raw/master/answer-peek.user.js) make sure you have a script manager.

[image: answer peek]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Answer Quick Peek
// @namespace    https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454538/
// @author       enki
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/questions/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

$(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $("#answers div.answer:first").before("<div id='top-answers-peek' style='padding-bottom: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eaebec; display: none;'><table style='margin:0 auto; '><tr></tr></table></div>");

    function score(e) {
      return new Number($(e).parent().find('.vote-count-post').text());
    }
    function compareByScore(a, b) {
      return score(b) - score(a);
    }
    $(":not(.deleted-answer) .answercell").slice(1).sort(compareByScore).slice(0, 5).each(function() {
        count++;
        var id = $(this).find(".short-link").attr("id").replace('link-post-', ''),
            score = $(this).prev().find(".vote-count-post").text(),
            icon = "vote-up-off";

        if (score > 0) {icon = "vote-up-on";}
        if (score < 0) {icon = "vote-down-on";}

        $("#top-answers-peek table tr").append("<td style='width: 100px; text-align: center;'><a href='#" + id + "'><i class='" + icon + "' style='margin-bottom: 0;'></i> Score: " + score + "</a></td>");
    });
    if (count > 0){
        $("#top-answers-peek").show();
        $("#top-answers-peek table").css("width", count * 100 + "px");
    }
});
```

Comment: Now, you need to post a this in [codereview.se], for a in-deep analysis.